# Is it possible to add a generic type that wraps values?

Tags: typescript

Let's assume this code:

```typescript
interface PersonData {
  name: string
  age: number
}

class Component<T> {}

class PersonComponent extends Component<PersonData> {}

function foo<T>(component: Component<T>, data: any) {
  // How to specify the correct type for `data` when passing observables as shown below?
}

const personData = { name: Observable.of('John'), age: Observable.of(35) }

foo(new PersonComponent, personData)
```

In other words: I want to be able to specify a type for `data` parameter that accepts type `T`, but all its values wrapped in Observables. So, I need a way to generically convert a type of `T` (which is an object/record), to the same type with all its values converted to Observables.

And a follow up question: would it be possible to extend that to deeply nested object hierarchies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to map the component props to observables:

```
interface PersonData {
  name: string
  age: number
}

class Component<T> { p!: T}

class PersonComponent extends Component<PersonData> {}

type ObservableRecord<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Observable<T[P]>
}
function foo<T>(component: Component<T>, data: ObservableRecord<T>) {
}

const personData = { name: Observable.of('John'), age: Observable.of(35) }    
foo(new PersonComponent, personData) 


const personDataErr = { name: Observable.of('John'), age: Observable.of("35") }    
foo(new PersonComponent, personDataErr) // err
```

Comment: This is very good. Do you know if it's possible to have a hierarchical/deep version of this? Like imagine `PersonData` having a field `deep: { structure: { value: number } }` and then calling the function with `deep: { structure: { value: Observable.of(5) } }`?

Comment: okay I got it with `[P in keyof T]: Observable<T[P]> | ObservableRecord<T[P]>`. Thanks a lot!